# Creating a new column from a dict mapping with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dataframe which has the `Material Types` Column.
I have a dictionary for `{'Material type, Value}`.

Now when I try to add a column `MAD_PER_MATERIAL` using Dictionary mapping for the same column Material types, I am getting NANs in the new column formed.

```
d=b.set_index('Material_Types').to_dict()
df["MAD_PER_MATERIAL"] = df["MATERIAL_Types"].map(d)
```

Comment: 1) paste your data frame 2) paste your dictionary.

Comment: This is an answer I gave on [**HowToMakeGoodExamples**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples/38466059#38466059).  In it I describe that your reputation is more than the points you've accumulated.  Believe it or not, it takes effort to answer these questions.  I enjoy doing it, but I also appreciate appreciation in the form of up-votes.  And when I see that answers haven't been accepted when they should be, I remember that too.  What that translates into is, I don't want to invest my time answering a question that won't get accepted.